# Starting Android VPN service that is not rooted anywhere

Tags: android, vpn, android-vpn-service, android-data-usage

I am looking to replicate the Ookla Speedtest displaying of data usage per application via the Android VPN service.

It appears they start a VPN service however they state that it is not routed through their servers.

How can this be done as you cannot initialise the VPN service with a null IP. Is there some sort of 'localhost' IP that can be used for this?

[image: Connection Request]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by simple packet manipulation, you will want to change the UDP and TCP packet headers to return to a new channel for the destination, in which case the channel will store a NAT session and return the packet to the appropriate place. Here's an example of something to get you started.

As for determining the application the packet originated from I have no idea how they may have done that, maybe you can check the originating socket and see if there's a way to determine what app opened the socket to begin with.

https://github.com/DrBrad/Android-VPN-to-Socket